# JQuery: parsing ajax call versus imbedded str

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am confused because I have two functions, one using ajax to get the data and the other getting it from a string.

```
function loadMenuData() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "./shoulders.json",
    success: function(data) {
        dataObj = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(dataObj, function( key, value) {
        $(document).find("#dropDownDest").append($('<option></option>').val(value.id).html(value.name));
    });
    }
});
}
function loadMenuDataX() {
    var str = '[{"id":"A","name":"Bart"},{"id":"B", "name":"Joe"},{"id":"C", "name":"Gomer"}]';
    dataObj = $.parseJSON(str);
    $.each(dataObj, function( key, value) {
        $(document).find("#dropDownDest").append($('<option></option>').val(value.id).html(value.name));
    });
}
```

I created the file `shoulders.json` buy pasting the `str` between the single quotes `'` into the file. If I call `loadMenuX`, it fills in the `<select></select>` correctly. If I call `loadMenu`, it doesn't fill anything in.

1. I have tried `JSON.parse` instead of the above and get the same behavior.
2. I was unable to use `$("#dropDownDest")` and had to use `$(document).find`. Why?
3. Hitting the DOM each loop seems to be excessive. What would be a better way to do the ajax version THAT WOULD WORK and be better?

Comment: you shouldnt need to use `parseJSON()` in the `ajax` call if its returning valid json. you should check that your json is valid json using something like http://jsonlint.com/ and then you should use your developers console to see if the ajax call is throwing any errors or even better add some error handling to your `ajax` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be a better way to do the ajax version THAT WOULD WORK and be better?

Because you're trying to get JSON file the better way is using **[jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)**, so you will be sure that the returned result is in json format :

```
$.getJSON( "./shoulders.json", function( json ) {
    $.each(json, function( key, value) {
        $("#dropDownDest").append('<option value="+value.id+">'+value.name+'</option>');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Acharki!  That helped.  I'm re-reading the jQuery documentation as the differences between parseJSON, JSON.parse, and getJSON along with $.get followed by perhaps parseJSON or JSON.parse aren't very clear to me.